# Movgrab with Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: command-line, downloads

Is there something that can be used in the command line in terminal to download videos from websites like Movgrab did?  Can't downlaod it or install movgrab with Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, so I followed the instructions from
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/movgrab-command-line-video-downloader.html

For any Linux distribution, download the source from

https://sites.google.com/site/columscode/home/movgrab

Then extract it and compile it in the terminal:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```